# Synchronize local database with external API

Tags: mysql, database, api, google-ads-api

I have a table containing about 500 000 rows. Once a day, I will try to synchronize this table with an external API. Most of the times, there are few- or no changes made since last update. My question is basically how should I construct my MySQL query for best performance? I have thought about using insert ignore, but it doesn't feel like the best way to go since only a few rows will be inserted and MySQL must loop through all rows in the table. I have also thought about using LOAD_DATA_INFILE to insert all rows in a temporary table and then select the rows not already in my original table, and then remove the temporary table. Maybe someone else has a better suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use a temporary table and the `LOAD DATA INFILE` bulk loader. The bulk loader is much more efficient that trying to insert records using a dynamically created query.

If you index your permanent tables with appropriate unique keys that relate to the keys in the API then you should find the the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements work pretty fast. An example of the type of `INSERT` query I use is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO keywords(api_adgroup_id, api_keyword_id, keyword_text, match_type, status) 
SELECT a.api_id, a.keyword_text, a.match_type, a.status
FROM tmp_keywords a LEFT JOIN keywords b ON a.api_adgroup_id = b.api_adgroup_id AND a.api_keyword_id = b.api_keyword_id
WHERE b.api_keyword_id IS NULL
```

In this example, I perform an `OUTER JOIN` on the `keywords` table to check if it already exists. Only new rows in the temporary table where there isn't a match in the main table (the `api_keyword_id` in the `keywords` table is `NULL`) are inserted.

Also note that in this example I need to use both the ad group id AND the keyword id to uniquely identify the keyword because the AdWords API gives the same keyword/match type combination the same id when it exists in more than one ad group.